# using nested/outer lock c#

Tags: c#, .net, syntax, locking

Is it ok to write such a code:

```
lock(syncObject) {
    try {

        do {
            // do some computations

            if(this.isStopped) break;
            Thread.Sleep(30000);

        } while(true);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.Log.Warn(ex);
    }
}
```

or would it be better to put this piece inside a `while` loop:

```
// ...
do {
    // do some computations

    lock(syncObject) {
        if(this.isStopped) break;
    }
    Thread.Sleep(30000);

} while(true);
// ...
```

Comment: what is `isStopped`? `if(this.isStopped)` suggests a `bool`; `lock(isStopped)` suggests an object... also: what is going to be changing the value of `this.isStopped`?

Comment: Sorry, overlooked that...

Comment: What is the intent of the code? It is okay to write the code if it achieves the goal you want, but you don't explain what that goal is.

Comment: The requirement for the lock is invisible from the question.  High odds that it is all wrong, testing a "stop the thread" condition should be done by EventWaitHandle.WaitOne(0) or BackgroundWorker.CancellationPending or CancellationToken.IsCancellationRequested

Comment: I was proposed not to use things like `autoResetEventInstance.WaitOne(0)` cause of infinite wait possibility.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

the advantage of having the `lock` on the inside of the loop is that it means that another thread can obtain the `lock` for the purpose of changing the value. However, this could also be achieved via `Monitor.Wait` / `Monitor.PulseAll`, which would mean that you don't need to wait the full 30s when it is exiting. For example:

```
lock(syncLock) {
    try {    
        do {
            // do some computations
            if(this.isStopped) break;
            Monitor.Wait(syncLock, 30000);
        } while(true);
    } 
    catch(Exception ex) {
        Logger.Log.Warn(ex);
    }
}
```

and to release it:

```
lock(syncLock) {
    this.isStopped = true;
    Monitor.PulseAll(syncLock);
}
```

Comment: The value of `isStopped` flag is changed by external call from a service manager. That's a windows service excerpt.

Comment: @lexeme the problem is that fields are not guaranteed to be re-read if you change the value on a different thread...

Comment: could you please explain this? Do you mean that once I stopped the service I might never restart it?

Comment: @lexeme I mean that with the first version in your question, there is a chance that `isStopped` will be cached, and it will never check the actual field again; threading is tricky...

Comment: Why do the `lock` inside a loop is available to another threads?

Comment: @lexeme because acquiring / releasing a lock involves either a *memory barrier* or a *full fence*, which is what guarantees that the field is re-read

Answer (score 1):

In your first example if you prevent any other code that uses `syncObject` from running.

In the second example you can enter the loop, do some stuff and then lock `syncObject` and do your check. This allows `syncObject` to be used by something else while your loop is busy doing other stuff.